# Importance for strict evaluation in a tail-recursive definition of the power function

Tags: haskell, tail-recursion

I understand this function and the tail-recursion but I can't figure out why the strict evaluation is important. Without the strict evaluation it would still be tail-recursive, right? So when will this function fail without strict evaluation?

```
turboPower a b = turboPower' 1 a b
  where
    turboPower' x a 0 = x
    turboPower' x a b
        | x `seq` a `seq` b `seq` False = undefined
        | even b = turboPower' x (a*a) (b `div` 2)
        | otherwise = turboPower' (x*a) a (b-1)
```

Comment: Btw, a better way to achieve the extra strictness these days is to use `BangPatterns`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will not fail (unless the exponent is *huge*, so the thunks may become large enough to overflow the stack), it will (may) just be less efficient, since without the strict evaluation, the arguments become thunks, leading to

```
turboPower' (let xN = let x(N-1) = ...; a(N-1) = ... in x(N-1)*a(N-1)) (let aN = let a(N-1) = ... in a(N-1)*a(n-1)) (let bN = ...)
```

It shouldn't be too dramatic here, since the level of nesting is logarithmic in the exponent, and thus remains small for all practical computations, but it would make a huge difference for example in

```
foo :: Integer -> Integer
foo n = go 0 n
  where
    go acc m
      | m < 1     = acc
      | otherwise = go (acc + m^3 + m `mod` 7) (m-1)
```

where the level of nesting is linear in `n`.